# How do I use conditional tags to place an object on all pages other than the front page?

Tags: php, html, image, wordpress, if-statement

I am trying to place a "back to home" button on all of the pages except the home page on a Wordpress site. I have successfully placed the item on all pages but cannot figure out how to remove it from the home page. I know that I probably need to use conditional tags but haven't worked with them much.

Here is the code I used in header.php:

```
<div class="outer"><a href="http://s416809079.onlinehome.us/"><img src="http://theshalomimaginative.com/testsite/wp-content/themes/pilot-fish/images/Untitled-1.png"/></a></div>
```

What would I need to use to have the image not on the homepage?

Any help in how to do this would be great! Thanks!

Here is the link to the site: http://s416809079.onlinehome.us/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`is_home()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) or [`is_front_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page). Which works depends on some peculiarities of your theme and your configuration. You'd have:

```
<?php
if (!is_home()) { ?>
    <div class="outer"><a href="http://s416809079.onlinehome.us/"><img src="http://theshalomimaginative.com/testsite/wp-content/themes/pilot-fish/images/Untitled-1.png"/></a></div><?php
} ?>
```

Or the same with `is_front_page()`.

Comment: I want the image on all of the pages except the front page. That is where I was confused. Is there a conditional tag for everything other than the front page? Or can I use the front page tag and have it not display the image?

Comment: Oops... sorry. i knew that but did it wrong anyway. Just add a negative to the conditional. I'll edit the code in my first post.

Comment: perfect. Thank you so much! How did you add the negative to the conditional?

Comment: The exclamation mark is a 'negate' operator. Those functions return boolean (true or false) so putting an exclamation mark in front reverses the value. If `is_home()` is `true` then `!is_home()` is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You should change of parameter CSS data in CSS files for property `.outer`.

```
div.outer img
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
```